# Apache Commons Math: where are the values for SummaryStatistics stored?

Tags: java, apache-commons-math

I am using Apache Commons Math in my web application. I need to use this class:

```
SummaryStatistics
```

However, I am puzzled by this description:

> Computes summary statistics for a stream of data values added using
>   the addValue method. The data values are not stored in memory, so this
>   class can be used to compute statistics for very large data streams.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/SummaryStatistics.html

If the values are not stored in memory, where are they stored? On disks? If on disks, what about the file names?  Can someone shed light on this? I would also like to know whether SummaryStatistics supports mutli-threads.

This is important to me because a web application allows multi-thread requests and I need to make sure one person's request does not overwrite the summary statistics for another person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not stored anywhere. The class only maintains the minimum summary values it needs, which are the sum, sum of squares, min, max, and a few more values. If in doubt, you can always check out [the source code](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/math4/stat/descriptive/SummaryStatistics.html#line.149).

Per thread-safety, the JavaDoc specifically says:

> This class is not thread-safe. Use [`SynchronizedSummaryStatistics`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/stat/descriptive/SynchronizedSummaryStatistics.html) if concurrent access from multiple threads is required.